# Why isn't Gnus scoring emails based on the To: or Cc: headers?

Tags: emacs, email, elisp

I use Gnus v5.13 in GNU Emacs 24.1.1 to read my email, and I'm having a trouble getting a simple score file to work.  Essentially, I want any mail that's sent to (or copies) a particular email address to be given a higher score.  My example score file, in `~/Mail/all.SCORE` is:

```
(("from"
  ("Mark Longair" 1000))
 ("To"
  ("mark-scoretesting@example.org" 1000)))
```

I'm making sure that that score file is being used by having added the following to my `~/.gnus` file:

```
(setq gnus-global-score-files
       '("~/Mail/all.SCORE"))
```

And this does seem to work properly for the rule that matches the `From` line - matching messages are highlighted, and when I type <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in the summary buffer, it shows a score of 1000 for those messages.  However, the "To" rule doesn't match.  The [documentation here probably explains this when it says](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Score-File-Format.html):

> Scoring can only be performed on these eight headers: From, Subject, References, Message-ID, Xref, Lines, Chars and Date.

[Other documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Scoring-On-Other-Headers.html), however, suggest that one can get around this limitation by the following steps:

> Put the following in your ~/.gnus.el file.
>
> ```
>  (setq gnus-extra-headers '(To Cc Newsgroups Keywords)
>        nnmail-extra-headers gnus-extra-headers)
> ```
>
> Restart Gnus and rebuild your nnml overview files with the `M-x nnml-generate-nov-databases` command. This will take a long time if you have much mail.
>
> Now you can score on ‘To’ and ‘Cc’ as “extra headers” like so: I e s p To RET  RET.
>
> See? Simple.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be that simple.  I've added the following to my `.gnus` file:

```
(setq gnus-extra-headers '(To Cc)
      nnmail-extra-headers gnus-extra-headers)
```

... restarted Emacs, and I've run `M-x nnml-generate-nov-databases`, but the rule in my score file for the "To" line, still isn't working, even if I type <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to rescore the articles in my summary buffer.

Can any suggest why this isn't working?

Comment: Do you have access to Usenet? In that case, there is a group for Gnus questions. It is much better if you ask there because almost no one here (or anywhere) uses Usenet anymore. I asked a couple of questions there (in the Gnus group) and got answers right away. Most likely, if you haven't removed it, you already have it added as a group.

Comment: @Emanuel Berg: thanks for the suggestion - I've tried asking the same thing here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.gnus/yh7j6jBEyI0/GsBHHz8CST4J

Comment: Right, that was the group I had in mind. It'll be interesting to see if I'm right or wrong.